# macport most recently installed packages

Tags: macos, macports

today I want to install one package named "octave"
in the middle, I found its dep are too many, so I canceled the installation.

However, there are some deps installed that I don't need.
How can I find out which packages are most recently installed by port.
Then I can pick them to remove.

Thanks

Comment: oh, I found a way:

    cd /opt/local/var/macports/software;
    ls -lart;

then I can see the lastly installed packages today.
although maybe there is some more precise way(check some log) can find out,too.

Comment: did you try `sudo port clean octave`?

Comment: `port clean` "removes temporary files that were created while installing a port", not any extra packages installed. I ended up [using port_cutleaves](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10149/how-to-remove-unused-macports-packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a way: `cd /opt/local/var/macports/software; ls -lart;` then I can see the lastly installed packages today. although maybe there is some more precise way(check some log) can find out,too.
>
> – CSJ Feb 29 at 6:20